# horizontal scrolling bash window (turn off line wrapping)

Tags: ubuntu, bash

já procurei em todos os fóruns, e no bing/google até cansar, não achei nada, provavelmente por manezice, será que é possível colocar um horizontal scroll bar no window bash?

Vi em alguns lugares, que isso não é uma boa ideia, mas penso em voltar a configuração ao terminar uma tarefa específica ou instalar um outro terminal, e quando precisar desse recurso usar um específico.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que nessa imagem, o comando passou da largura da janela, e o ideal seria ele colocar um scroll horizontal.

Comment: Qual OS? Qual Bash?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04, MATE-terminal

Comment: vi algumas pessoas falando do `less`, mas não consegui utilizá-lo, falaram também do `terminator`, mas também não consegui o scroll horizontal

Answer (score 0):

#### --- Edição ---

consegui uma opção melhor ainda, com o comando `most` 
ele não vem instalado no ubuntu 18.
para instalar: `sudo apt-get install most -y`
depois é só utilizá-lo com:
`docker ps -a | most`
A navegação dele achei melhor que com o `less`, e ele já retira o word-wrapper por default.

---

Consegui com o comando `less`

Por exemplo, ao executar o comando `docker ps -a` o resultado não cabe na largura da janela.

Então, podemos usar o `less` que possuí inúmeras opções para exibir um arquivo, ou o output de algum comando.

o comando para ele parar de fazer `word wrapper` é:
`less -S --chop-long-lines`

para pegar a saída do comando e exibir com `less`:
`docker ps -a | less -S --chop-long-lines`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Achei a resposta em: https://superuser.com/questions/272818/how-to-turn-off-word-wrap-in-less